# typoscript + automaketemplate - different template on root page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In my typo3 website I have a root page and many sub pages which most of them share the same structure. Therefore I have created my template with automaketemplate on the root page so it can be shared through all of the sub pages. For the ones that I have a slightly different structure I can create an extension template. My problem is with the root page - its structure is different and I need to use another template file. But I can't create an extension template for it since it already has a main template. What is the workaround on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your site structure looks like this:

```
root (home)
 |- Subpage 1
 |- Subpage 2
 |- etc.
```

I would suggest you change it to this one:

```
root (Shortcut to Home)
 |- Home
 |- Subpage 1
 |- Subpage 2
 |- etc.
```

That way all your templates can inherit from `root` but Home can have a completely different structure.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to solve my problem. Just one more thing - in the root page where most of my typoscript is located I am parsing a HTML for the template using automaketemplate. Now in Home (to which root points to) I have the following code: plugin.tx_automaketemplate_pi1.content.file = fileadmin/template/index.html. This loads the index template but the navigation isn't parsed. Do I need to repeat the entire code from the root to make it work?

Comment: It looks like the template looses the marker information. To avoid this, you can build your navigation in a separate object (e.g. `lib.navi.one` for the main navigation) and fill the marker in your templates via copying them, e.g. `page.20.subparts.MENU < lib.navi.one`